# Add /Wall when running code analysis only?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, sal

During my regular builds, I have `/W4` turned on, with a few additional warnings as well, and some that are simply disabled due to too many false positives with Visual Studio. This mostly works okay, but I'd still like, from time to time, to check on all warnings which `/Wall` would give.

My preference would be to do this during Code Analysis, which I run about once a week anyway. I already have a custom ruleset file for CA, but I can't figure out how to enable additional non-CA warnings in it. I've also tried looking in the .vcxproj files to see if there's anything in there which is specific to CA, but I couldn't find anything.

Additional info: I use CMake to create the projects, so it would be preferred if it's something I can do in there, but I can probably modify my CMake myself to work with potential solutions. Also, all projects are C++ (not CLI) except one which is C#.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but what about creating a new [configuration type](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-specify-my-own-configurations-for-generators-that-allow-it-) and adding `/ANALYZE` and `/Wall` to `CXXFLAGS` for it?

Comment: Why not just make another configuration that uses /Wall, but otherwise is the same? Also from my experience there is no need to suppress any /W4 warnings.

Comment: @user786653, I don't use the Release mode, so I've added `/Wall` to its settings, which seems to work okay. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's something.

Comment: @user7860670, there's a few in `/W4` which have a lot of false positives (I have several open issues with MS for them). We also use Qt, which generates literally thousands of warnings at level 4 due to the issues occurring in the header files.